# Azure and NX, error while running a pipeline : npm : Another process, with id 4224, is currently running ngcc

Tags: angular, azure-devops, nomachine-nx

I'm trying to run a pipeline with Azure, when it comes to build, it fails with this error :

[image]

When I run the `nx affected --target=build --base=origin/master --prod --parallel` command locally, I also have the `Another process...` message but it doesn't show as an error which lets the build continues. But on Azure it just fails :(

Any idea how I can solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation, I found out the problem was with powershell.

Here is the yaml code I was using :

```
- task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: 'Running build'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: 'npm run nx affected -- --target=build --base=origin/master --prod --parallel'
```

It looks like Powershell exited on this error which doesn't seem to be the case with either cmd.exe or pwsh.
Here is the version that works :

```
- pwsh: 'npm run nx affected -- --target=build --parallel --base=origin/master --prod'
        displayName: 'Running build'
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with how NGCC runs, you can reference it here:

[GitHub Issue 35362](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35362)

and as a work around add this to your package.json file:  (in the script section)

```
"postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points",
```

it also appears to be blocking using the --parallel flag.  try dropping that.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Unfortunately, this script is already in my package.json

Comment: are you running concurrent builds? and have you tried to delete the lock file from   node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/ ?

Comment: Yes, NX tooling allows to run build on multiple projects at the same time as you can see on the screenshot

Comment: Well, Im not sure about the lockfile as the scripts run in an Azure agent and not locally

Comment: ah, i assumed you had access to the node_modules folder ,  did you try dropping the --parallel flag?

Comment: the --parallel flag allows scripts to run in parallel, this is not about concurrent builds... :/

Comment: the weird part is that locally the message `Another process...` doesnt show as an error. It does on Azure though.

Comment: Wait actually it seems to work when removing --parallel, I need to make some tests to check if that is really the thing that make it works because I've changed some other details. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: np, i also edited the answer above to help others who might run into this problem

Comment: Ok so after more investigation, it looks like it has more to do with powershell. I was using `task: PowerShell@2` to use these scripts which led to those errors. I tried with `pwsh` and also just `script:` and it seems to work even with --parallel

Comment: @GreatHawkeye It seems that you've found the workaround, please consider adding that as answer :)