# Nx build - Another process, with id xxx, is currently running ngcc

Tags: angular, bitbucket-pipelines, angular13, angular-compiler, nx.dev

I have a Nx monorepo that contains 2 projects. When I build these projects locally everything works as expected, but when I try to build the same projects on the build server I get the error

```
Another process, with id 111, is currently running ngcc.
Waiting up to 250s for it to finish.
(If you are sure no ngcc process is running then you should delete the lock-file at /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/.ngcc_lock_file.)
```

This is probably caused by command `nx affected:build --all --parallel --configuration=production`. That runs all builds in parallel, where somehow both builds run `ngcc`, which in turn locks certain files in the `node_modules` directory. So much is clear to me. But the problem is that I've tried almost every suggested fix, but the warning is still there, slowing down the build significantly and even making it fail in some cases.

---

**Versions**

- **Angular**: 13.2.x (it gave the same error on v12.x)
- **Nx**: 13.8.x
- **Node**: v14.17.x
- **Pipeline**: Bitbucket pipelines

---

**Adding ngcc to post-install**

According to some answers ([here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36278), [here](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/6842), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61122763/another-process-with-id-is-currently-running-ngcc), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62070279/azure-and-nx-error-while-running-a-pipeline-npm-another-process-with-id-42) and many more) the best workaround is to add `ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main` or even `ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --create-ivy-entry-points --first-only` to the `postinstall` in the package.json. Since Nx V12 this is automatically added when generating a new monorepo via Nx, but doesn't seem to fix the message on the build server (never had any issues locally)

(`"postinstall": "node ./decorate-angular-cli.js && ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main",`)

**Delete the lock-file**

I've tried to delete the lock-file before the build begins, because I thought maybe the `postinstall` would create the lock-file, but somehow doesn't get the time to delete it. But all my attempts show that there is no lock-file before the build starts.

Script:

```
if [ -f "$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/$NGCC_LOCATION" ]; then rm $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/$NGCC_LOCATION; else echo "no lock-file"; fi

$NGCC_LOCATION="node_modules/.ngcc_lock_file."
```

Always results in `no lock file`

---

**Caching**

The node_modules are cached in the build server, so that it can be used in the separate pipeline steps. The script is as follows:

```
pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    '**':
      - step: *install
      - parallel:
          - step: *lint
          - step: *test
          - step: *build
```

Where every step uses the `node` cache that is created on the `install`-step. I cannot verify if the ngcc result is stored in the cache, but since the whole `node_modules` is cached after the install step and the ngcc result is added to the node_modules I am guessing it is stored.

---

Since none of the above is fixing the warning, is there something I am missing or is this just the way ngcc works for now?

Comment: I am stuck on this too, but "The ngcc lock is an Angular safeguard to prevent erroneous compilations, while there is a compilation ongoing currently, of any ViewEngine libraries in the node_modules folder." so I guess bypassing it is a bad thing. Ideally we should be able to run ngcc once before building any project, and then use the result for the parallel, that way we only run it once. But couldn't find a proper way to do it yet.

Comment: looks like it's possible to prevent that by adding a delay between each build task. I'm going to add this part of [tskmgr](https://github.com/mathpaquette/tskmgr) build system (nx cloud alternative). I'll let you know I have the exact same issue now.

Comment: Same problem here. Angular: 11.2.x. Nx: 11.6.x. Node: v10.24.x. Pipeline: Jenkins multibranch pipelines (Powershell executes the Nx commands from within the pipeline).

Comment: Also stucked on this problem :( angular 14 @Mr.wiseguy did you find any work around ?

Comment: I fixed it with the accepted answer below. Just before I did a build I set the BAZEL_TARGET on true in the pipeline. Not the prettiest solution, but worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this problem is addressed in the following GitHub issue:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/38216

And in particular by the following comments:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/38216#issuecomment-666302873
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/38216#issuecomment-672563429

Essentially it's necessary to trick the [Angular Compiler Webpack Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngtools/webpack) into thinking it's running under [Bazel](https://bazel.build/) by setting an environment variable (BAZEL_TARGET) for the Node processes running on the build system to read. Following is the relevant code snippet from the plugin's [ngcc processor](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/13.2.6/packages/ngtools/webpack/src/ngcc_processor.ts#L58-L60):

```
if (process.env.BAZEL_TARGET) {
    return;
}
```

This prevents the plugin from running ngcc over the node_modules directory, which creates the lock file, which in turn prevents the parallel processes from executing. Since ngcc is already being run via the package.json postinstall script, there should be no need to run it again via the plugin, although the argument goes that the plugin can't be blamed for not knowing about the postinstall script.

As is mentioned in the GitHub issue, the solution may be a bit of a hacky workaround but in testing with the versions/tech mentioned in my [earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71296689/nx-build-another-process-with-id-xxx-is-currently-running-ngcc#comment129607390_71296689) seems to have been working reliably.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Not sure the BAZEL_TARGET hack works anymore, at least, I was unable to get it to work for our app

Comment: @LocalPCGuy Interesting. The check for the environment variable has been in the Angular CLI codebase since at least version 9 as far as I can tell, so I'm not seeing any reason it shouldn't work. Are you certain the environment variable is being set on your CI server for each Node process? (I found patch-package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) useful for adding logging statements to the third-party code.)

Comment: This code has been supressed => BAZEL hack wont work anymore
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/c8ac660d8b13922be7ebcc92dfd5b18392602c40#diff-ad002d194bd8ec810786bb7aa9f3b66c21dda7f336809bf2974648c304a81a86

Comment: @Deunz Your commit shows that NGRCC is being removed from angular (#happydance); however, it's tagged with 16.1.0-rc.0. Currently, I'm using angular 15.2.7, and the BAZEL_TARGET trick seems to work.

Comment: @david_i_smith I've been looking for a resolution to this off and on for years. Thanks for this.

Comment: I just said the trick is not time proof. Angular 16 is out, Our 900 angular app scope is not concerned to as no angular 16 app are yet built, but I can say it's tomorrow ! Thus I am not interested in this hack. WHat would be great is a fkin feature to DISABLE it the same way : if (disableMeFeature) return;

Comment: @Deunz The change you linked alludes to the fact that Angular 16 *completely removes* ngcc, so this "hack" is no longer applicable for Angular 16 projects as ngcc is not a part of the build process any longer. If you are working with Angular 15 or below, this is still the approach to take, as ngcc will still be a component of your build process.